# Binding 3rd variable in N1QL statement doesn't work

Tags: node.js, typescript, couchbase, sql++

Currently this works, it queries the database and returns the JSON data we need:

```
const QUERY: string = 'SELECT * FROM `default` where _type=$1 and type=$3';
const params: string[] = [this.getSchema(), queryParams[0].key, queryParams[0].value];
```

However, as soon as we replace `type` with `$2` the query returns nothing. I.e. this doesn't work:

```
const QUERY: string = 'SELECT * FROM `default` where _type=$1 and $2=$3';
const params: string[] = [this.getSchema(), queryParams[0].key, queryParams[0].value];
```

Even though `$2` evaluates to "type"

An error is returned from couchbase: "An unknown N1QL error occurred. This is usually related to an out-of-memory condition."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dynamic query instead of a constant query :

```
'SELECT * FROM `default` where _type=$1 and ' + queryParams[0].key + '=$3'
```

Comment: I've tried that and it works, my only concern is that this can open us up to sql injection through `queryParams[0].key`, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes if your variable injected in your query come from a user entry else no